# Keynote 6.2 - hyperlinks on shapes without filling

Tags: keynote, links

I created a presentation that I need to use frequently, using the prior build of keynote and used rectangular shapes to create my links. I superimposed these rectangles on images, so they have no filling, only the border. Previously, when I clicked on any part of the rectangle and its inner area the link would work. But since the update to 6.2 the link is only active when I click on the border, which is not how I want it to be. Is there any way I can get this to work again, preferably without having to click on each of the over 200 links I have in the presentation?